# EXCEL VBA CODE for meeting invitation in outlook to multiple users separetely with no conflict

Tags: excel

I created vba code for sending out outlook invitation. it worked succesfuly. but i missed two parts and wanted to add it but don't know how. asking for your help

1. firstly  i have the list of user's emails in excel and want to send the same invitation to all of them separately.
2. want to and  (check names)
3. want to add code to check availability of recipients from suggested items.

asking for your help.
thanks

BTW: this is my code:

```
**Sub sendmeetinginvitation()
Dim O As Outlook.Application
Set O = New Outlook.Application
Dim OMT As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set OMT = O.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
OMT.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
Dim mylist As String
mylist = OMT.Recipients.Add("........")
With OMT
.Subject = "test1"
.Start = #9/1/2020 12:00:00 PM#
.Duration = 60
.Display
.Send
End With
End Sub**
```